# Besides iCarly, has there ever been an (official) adult sequel to a kids' series?

Tags: trope, icarly

Previously I asked [What's the term for some sequel where we see the characters in the original but much older?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/110320/whats-the-trope-for-some-sequel-where-we-see-the-characters-in-the-original-but) where an answer is [Character Aged with the Actor](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/CharacterAgedWithTheActor) but in the examples I've mentioned the [Motion Picture Association film rating](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Motion_Picture_Association_film_rating_system) or whatever doesn't change (except possibly Rugrats vs All Grown Up).

With [iCarly (2007-12)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ICarly) however, its [2021 revival](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ICarly_(2021_TV_series)) definitely has a different rating. Like...there's sex and stuff.

Is iCarly the 1st of its kind? Or is there precedence?

Note 1: When I say official, I mean to exclude not only 'Rule 34' or whatever and other fanfiction but also things like [Once Upon a Time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Once_Upon_a_Time_(TV_series)).

Note 2: As for the reverse case of kids' sequel to an adult series, I can't think of anything, but I don't imagine it's as rare. Maybe Back to the Future animated series. I really mean here adult sequel to kids' series.

Comment: I haven't seen the Punky Brewster revival to know if it's existence on streaming factored into a ratings change of said content between each series, but of so, I think it's revival premiered slightly before iCarly's.

Comment: There were a couple spinoffs from Little House On The Prairie that dealt with more adult issues.

Comment: @JohnnyBones Post as answer?

Comment: @DarthLocke Post as answer?

Comment: @BCLC I'm would think there might be one earlier, like Johnny Bones' answer, so there is kind of no point given that this one only predates yours by only a few months, as the Q is about trying to find the earliest one(s). That's why I mentioned it in comments. I wanted to do more research/wait and see what others found first.

Comment: @DarthLocke Ok thanks, but you can still post as answer. Anything as precedence would be interesting to know. I don't suspect there are many.

Comment: @BCLC first appearance Q's are on topic, but identity Q's are not, and by posting mine I would be setting the precedent for it, unless there are no others that perfectly match your criteria, but you have already selected J.Bones answer as thee best answer, so I presume that it meets what you wanted well enough.

Comment: @DarthLocke Just because I accept an answer, doesn't mean I'm not open to other answers :D

Comment: I really don't know what is going on with you. Posting your answer as an answer actually was the correct approach, rather than putting it into your question somehow. I have no idea why you suddenly think you ought to add it into your question and delete your answer. But in any case, this whole thing is going to get locked for now.

Comment: Regarding kids sequels to adult series, there have been things like the late 1980s [Robocop](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RoboCop_(American_TV_series)) cartoon, and a [Rambo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rambo:_The_Force_of_Freedom) cartoon. And less adult in the original, mid-70s Saturday morning cartoon [Star Trek](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_Trek:_The_Animated_Series), and Happy Days which was originally a family show had [a childish animated spin-off](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Fonz_and_the_Happy_Days_Gang).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

### Yes, there are precedents

While I'm sure there have been plenty of others, one that immediately comes to mind is [*The Brady Brides* (1981)](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0081836/), which was a spinoff of [*The Brady Bunch* (1969-74)](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0063878/).  While there wasn't a huge jump in content, it did go from "G-Rated" to "Almost PG-Rated".  For instance, in the very first episode there is an exchange between Marcia and Jan, when looking at a potential home's kitchen:

> Marcia: "There's even a wine rack!"
> Jan: "Betty Crocker could get crocked."

There's also the neighbor, who introduces herself as "'Miss', by choice.  Because men only have one thing on their mind."  Clearly an allusion to sex, without being as explicit as shows are today.

These examples are outside the scope of the usually wholesome Brady Bunch image.

Answer (score 4):

[Velma](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Velma_(TV_series)) is the 2023 animated series reworking the origin story of the [Scooby Doo](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scooby-Doo) franchise. It is the first show in the franchise [aimed at adults](https://www.theguardian.com/commentisfree/2023/jan/18/velma-lesbian-detective-scooby-doo-fans-hate?CMP=Share_AndroidApp_Other). The critics [said](https://www.huffingtonpost.co.uk/entry/velma-hbo-max-review_n_63bc6303e4b0ae9de1c07df1):

> “Velma,” [...], delves deeper into her narrative, giving her an emotionally unavailable dad, a mysteriously missing mother, friends, frenemies, and a sexuality while rightly positioning her as the central gumshoe in an increasingly bizarre case of murdered hot girls at her school.

Answer (score 2):

**There is another example from recent memory**

I'd consider [Saved by the Bell (2020)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Saved_by_the_Bell_(2020_TV_series)) as another example. It has a lot more language and mature themes compared to the [original series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Saved_by_the_Bell) and [Good Morning Miss Bliss](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Good_Morning,_Miss_Bliss).

Some curse words used includes h***, b****, and d***. An example of mature themes includes a mention about pornography.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if it fits your criteria, but there used to be a series called
Punky Brewster - https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0086787/ in the 80s. From the looks of it that would have been a kids/teen series.

The series was recently rebooted with the same actress who played the protagonistic child in the original series.
https://www.imdb.com/title/tt10436362/
From the setup it appears to be a young adult/parenting/family sitcom now.

Comment: Lol way to steal Darth Locke's answer. Anyhoo thanks XD

Comment: @BCLC My bad, i didn't see his comment. If he decides to post his own answer, i can yield this one.

Comment: Oh you're honest? ok fine. lol. but it's ok BestGuess even if you're dishonest don't yield. I want both of you to post your own answers.   Lol

Comment: No worries. I'm cool with it. But I did expliain why I didn't, because it goes to identity Q's which are off topic on this site, but first appearences are not, hence why Johnny Bones answer should be conisdered the best answer (so far).

Answer (score 1):

In the UK there was a Saturday morning TV show specifically for kids called '[Tiswas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tiswas)'.

In 1982 it was rebranded as '[O.T.T](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/O.T.T._(TV_series))' and broadcast in an 11.00pm timeslot specifically for adults with many of the same presenters.

> O.T.T. ("Over the Top") is a late-night adult version of the anarchic ATV children's show Tiswas, and was made by its ITV franchise successor Central Independent Television. It was broadcast at 11.00pm on Saturday nights for one series from 2 January until 3 April 1982. O.T.T. was created and presented by Chris Tarrant, and also starred Tiswas performers John Gorman, Lenny Henry and Bob Carolgees. Helen Atkinson-Wood was the female sidekick replacement for Sally James, who stayed behind to present the concurrent and final series of Tiswas alone with special appearances from Ellen Thomas.

Answer (score 0):

I know that it's not strictly live action, but the 1980s children's cartoons He-Man, Thundercats, Visionaries and Transformers all had comic book revivals that were aimed at the original child audiences when they were older teens. They contained sex and violence above PG-13 levels.

The Michael Bay version of Transformers is also aimed at a more grown up audience and has sex, violence and drugs in it.

Saved By the Bell had the College Years, which was aimed at a slightly older audience. Though not "adult".

Comment: Teenage Mutant Ninja Turtles has varied quite a bit in intended age of the various adaptations, although the original comic books were aimed at adults, so it may not count.

Answer (score 0):

Kids TV series - [The Banana Splits](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Banana_Splits).

Slasher movie for adults - [The Banana Splits Movie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Banana_Splits_Movie)