# Cases where voice actor reprises role in live-action adaptation

Tags: production, animation, trope, acting

Aside from anime and the examples listed below, **what instances have there been of voice actors reprising their roles in live-action adaptations?** (For anime, see [this post](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/67655/both-the-voice-and-the-live-action-in-anime).)

1. Patton Oswalt voices Dementor in the *Kim Possible* cartoon and reprises the role in the live-action film.

[image: Patton Oswalt as Dementor]

2. [Haruka Fukuhara](https://www.reddit.com/r/Kaguya_sama/comments/ne4mmh/haruka_fukuhara_voice_actor_for_tsubame_koyasu_in/) voices Tsubame Koyasu in the [Kaguya-sama](https://twitter.com/eiga_natalie/status/1394114729530912771) anime and then reprises the role in the live-action films.

[image: Haruka Fukuhara as Tsubame Koyasu]

3. And not exactly the same but pretty close: Riisa Naka who voiced [Makoto Konno](https://thegirlwholeptthroughtime.fandom.com/wiki/Makoto_Konno) in [*The Girl Who Leapt Through Time* (2006 film)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Girl_Who_Leapt_Through_Time_(2006_film)) and then plays Makoto's cousin [Akari Yoshiyama](https://thegirlwholeptthroughtime.fandom.com/wiki/Akari_Yoshiyama) who is about the same age I guess in the 2010 live movie [*Time Traveller: The Girl Who Leapt Through Time*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_Traveller:_The_Girl_Who_Leapt_Through_Time).

[image: Riisa Naka]

<sup>Source for the left part of the image above is [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zWzRO0tqeIo).</sup>

Scope:

1. Exclude, of course, CGI characters, such as Nakamura Shidō II AKA Mikihiro Ogawa and Brian Drummond, who play Ryuk in both the *Death Note* anime and live-action film adaptations and Rufus (CGI character played by Nancy Cartwright) in *Kim Possible*.
2. Exclude dubbing cases like when the dub actors of the [*Death Note* anime reprise their roles in the dub for the *Death Note* live-action films](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/8591/is-there-a-reason-why-the-actors-sound-exactly-the-same-as-their-anime-counterpa).
3. The animated portrayal - or the radio series portrayal - must **precede** the live portrayal.

   - 3.1. 'I'm not sure why you have the rule that the animation must come first. ' → Otherwise, there would be a lot, like animated versions of real people, e.g., [Avril Lavigne on Family Guy](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2XWcTz7ajf8), [Scooby Doo & WWE](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GYQ-jRgCneg), [Christopher Lloyd in BTTF I think](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Back_to_the_Future_(TV_series)), etc.

Or if you think of something that's out of scope but might actually be in the spirit of this question, then feel free to comment it!

Comment: The 'rules' of this little quiz seem quite arbitrary ... like why is GGI (of course) excluded, but why is someone playing a relative of someone included.

Comment: @iandotkelly haha fair. too many examples if include CGI. not many examples for the relative case.

Comment: Doesn't quite fit - [The Amazing Maurice and His Educated Rodents](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Amazing_Maurice_and_His_Educated_Rodents) David Tennant played Darktan in the radio play 2003 & again in the recent Sky movie 2022.

Comment: Re VTC Needs more focus - lol what do you want? How is this any different from [Besides iCarly, has there ever been an (official) adult sequel to a kids' series?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/117455/besides-icarly-has-there-ever-been-an-official-adult-sequel-to-a-kids-series)

Comment: @Tetsujin thanks for sharing! edited to include radio. feel free to post as answer if the movie is live...?

Comment: 2nd VTC: what's the community specific reason?

Comment: This would probably get fewer close votes if you made it an on-topic [[tag:first-appearance]] question instead.

Comment: @galacticninja How do I do that?

Comment: @BCLC See the other on-topic questions tagged [[tag:first-appearance]] for a starting point. Basically, only ask about the first appearance of what you described. I'd also remove "relative of a similar/related character," as it broadens your question (and makes it more likely to stay closed).

Comment: @galacticninja only 1st appearance? I wanna see more than just that. I wanna see 2nd appearance 3rd and so on. but anyhoo i made riisa naka an example

Comment: @galacticninja what's your opinion of [Besides iCarly, has there ever been an (official) adult sequel to a kids' series?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/117455/besides-icarly-has-there-ever-been-an-official-adult-sequel-to-a-kids-series)

Comment: @BCLC The "(official) adult sequel to a kids' series" question seems to be fine by me. This question is fine by me too. However, at least 4 other close voters don't think so. If it does not get reopened after a day or two, you could appeal or ask for a discussion about this question at [meta].

Answer (score 2):

The Hitch-Hiker's Guide To The Galaxy started as [a radio series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Hitchhiker%27s_Guide_to_the_Galaxy_(radio_series)) then later as a [TV series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Hitchhiker%27s_Guide_to_the_Galaxy_(TV_series)).  Several actors played the same role in both versions, including Simon Jones (Arthur), Peter Jones (The Book), Mark Wing-Davy (Zaphod) and Stephen Moore (Marvin).

It hasn't been broadcast yet, but the main cast of the animated series [Star Trek:Lower Decks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_Trek:_Lower_Decks) [are to appear in a live action episode](https://trekmovie.com/2022/07/23/star-trek-strange-new-worlds-to-cross-over-with-lower-decks-in-season-2/) of Star Trek:Strange New Worlds, playing the same characters.  The character art was modeled after the actors with the intent to do this.

I'm not sure why you have the rule that the animation must come first. I suppose  [Star Trek: The Animated Series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_Trek:_The_Animated_Series) wouldn't count.

Comment: 'I'm not sure why you have the rule that the animation must come first. ' --> Otherwise there would be a lot. Like animated versions of real people eg [Avril Lavigne on Family Guy](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2XWcTz7ajf8), [Scooby Doo & WWE](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GYQ-jRgCneg), [Christopher Lloyd in BTTF I think](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Back_to_the_Future_(TV_series)), etc

Comment: Thanks Pete! Feel free to make 2 posts - 1 for Star Trek and 1 for H2G2